# Adding attributes in chaining way in dplyr package

Tags: r, attributes, attr, chaining, dplyr

Is there any way to add an attribute using chaining sequence code operator `%>%` from `dplyr` package?

```
> library(dplyr)
> iris %>%
+   attr( "date") = Sys.Date()
Error in iris %>% attr("date") = Sys.Date() : 
  could not find function "%>%<-"
>
```

Thanks for respone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also consider `setattr` from "data.table":

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
names(attributes(iris))
# [1] "names"     "row.names" "class" 

iris %>% setattr(., "date", Sys.Date())
names(attributes(iris))
# [1] "names"     "row.names" "class"     "date" 
attributes(I2)$date
# [1] "2014-09-04"
```

Of course, no chaining is actually required for something like this. You could just do:

```
setattr(iris, "date", Sys.Date())
```

This allows you to set attributes without copying the objects in question:

```
> v1 <- 1:4
> v2 <- 1:4
> tracemem(v1)
[1] "<0x0000000011cffa38>"
> attr(v1, "foo") <- "bar"
tracemem[0x0000000011cffa38 -> 0x0000000011d740f8]: 
> tracemem(v2)
[1] "<0x0000000011db2da0>"
> setattr(v2, "foo", "bar")
> attributes(v2)
$foo
[1] "bar"
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice solution and not so archaic.

Comment: Using the `structure` (as part of the base package) accomplishes the same thing without the dependency on data.table. See answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42443024/1504321

Answer (score 12):

You can do it this way :

```
R> tmp <- iris %>% `attr<-`("date", Sys.Date())

R> attr(tmp,"date")
[1] "2014-09-04"
```

This relies on the fact that calling :

```
attr(x, "foo") <- "bar"
```

is equivalent to calling :

```
x <- `attr<-`(x, "foo", "bar")
```

Comment: Wonderfull! Thank You very much. That opened mine eyes.

Answer (score 7):

If the attribute name is known, the simplest solution is to use the `structure` function:

```
library(dplyr)

iris <- 
  iris %>%
  structure( date=Sys.Date() )

attr(iris,"date")  # "2017-02-24"
```

When the attribute name is not know, @juba's solutions seems to be the best alternative.